# Is it possible to know the typeset of this sample?

Tags: fonts, typography

I'm looking for the typeset of the following format:

The link to this full report is: [thesis report](http://www.coep.org.in/page_assets/341/121222006_-_Bhambhlani.pdf)

[image]

[image]

My current latex MWE is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,onecolumn]{report}

\usepackage[dvips]{graphics}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{epsfig}

\setlength{\textwidth}{6.27in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.69in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0.0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.0in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0.0in}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\linespread{1}
\selectfont

\setlength\parindent{24pt}

\newenvironment{acknowledgments} {\renewcommand\abstractname{Acknowledgements}\begin{abstract}} {\end{abstract}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{acknowledgments}
I would like to express my sincere and deepest gratitude to my dissertation guide Dr. Sunil B. Mane for his continuous support and understanding throughout this journey. I am grateful to all the volunteers who shared their email history for preperation of the dataset without which the research would have seriously hampered. I would like to thank all the faculty members of Department of Computer Engineering \& IT and the helpdesk team for providing me with the necessary help whenever required. I express my gratitude to my colleagues with whom I had valuable discussions on the project. Lastly, but importantly, to my parents who have loved me unconditionally all the time. 
\end{acknowledgments}

\end{document}
```

And it is displayed as

[image]

I'm not able to figure out this typeset. It appears to be a different font. Please can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest difference seems to be the linespread.The fontsize is difficult to judge from images.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,onecolumn]{report}

\usepackage[dvips]{graphics}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{epsfig}
%
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.27in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.69in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0.0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.0in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0.0in}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\linespread{1.5}        % Vertical spacing between lines
\selectfont             % Select the specified font
%
\newenvironment{acknowledgments} {\renewcommand\abstractname{Acknowledgements}\begin{abstract}} {\end{abstract}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{acknowledgments}
\linespread{1}\selectfont  
I would like to express my sincere and deepest gratitude to my dissertation guide Dr. Sunil B. Mane for his continuous support and understanding throughout this journey. I am grateful to all the volunteers who shared their email history for preperation of the dataset without which the research would have seriously hampered. I would like to thank all the faculty members of Department of Computer Engineering \& IT and the helpdesk team for providing me with the necessary help whenever required. I express my gratitude to my colleagues with whom I had valuable discussions on the project. Lastly, but importantly, to my parents who have loved me unconditionally all the time. 
\end{acknowledgments}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. The link to the report is: http://www.coep.org.in/page_assets/341/121222006_-_Bhambhlani.pdf Is there any way I can figure out the font?

Comment: @user5155835 see https://superuser.com/questions/117443/how-to-know-which-fonts-are-used-in-selected-part-of-a-pdf-document

Comment: Removing the \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} and having linespread{1.2}. The font is the default font given by report class. Please can you update your answer with these details?